# Stopping logging info from interrupting CLI session?

Tags: fortigate, fortinet, logging

With cisco devices the logging synchronous command will stop logging output from interrupting the the CLI session. Is there an equivalent command for the fortigate firewalls? i.e. When running a debug on the firewall is it possible to keep the cli prompt below of the debug output at all times so that typing/input is never interrupted?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can filter the debug console: https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD33882 -- or perhaps start a second SSH session - one for config changes and one for debugging?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible in FOS. Even with multiple (ssh) terminal windows, debug info will be printed on ALL windows. Multiple terminals will only faciliate command input.